# How do I print my square box correctly in the terminal?

Tags: python, printing, terminal

I am trying to draw a box with symbols on the terminal. The shape is created by a class object. I want to know how I could print my object dynamically.

```
class Box:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw_box(self):
        print('+ ' * self.width)
        for s in range(self.height-2):
            print('+ ', ' ' * (self.width-1), ' +')
        print('+ ' * self.width)


# Create and Run code
box = Box(5,4)
box.draw_box()
```

But you can see below that the "width" coding of the box is broken. It was a little difficult to test because every time I changed the width and height arguments of my object, I would have to "fix" it to print correctly by either adding or subtracting a hard-coded number from or to `self.width`. The text are the `width` and `height` argument I tested for.

```
+ + + + + + + + + + + 
+             + (11,7)
+             +
+             +
+             +
+             +
+ + + + + + + + + + + 
>>> #Bad output
+ + + + + (5,5)
+       +
+       +
+       +
+ + + + +
>>> #Good output
```

Comment: Where you have written `' ' * (self.width-1)`, how exactly did you decide that `self.width - 1` is the appropriate number of spaces to use? If you increase `width` by 1, what change do you expect to the length of each line? (Hint: are you adding anything else to the top and bottom lines besides a `+` symbol?)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) This also goes for incorrect output, as long as it's plain text - you can, and should, copy and paste text out of the IDLE window and show it to us, formatted as code.

Comment: My problem with it is that `print` isn't printing the whitespace and characters in proper proportion to `width`.

Comment: Yes, it absolutely is printing the spaces as the same width as the `+` symbols. It can only possibly do so, because the font is controlled by the environment (IDLE, or else a terminal window), not by Python. The problem is that you don't print the correct number of spaces. (You could also see this when trying to copy the text, since scrolling slowly over the text would highlight one space at a time.) That's why I asked you the questions I did - in order to point out to you the error in your logic for calculating the number of spaces.

Comment: IDLE is irrelevant as long as you do not change from the default fixed-pitch font to a proportional font.  Another fixed pitch font is fine.  You can tell by looking at the ASCII part of the font sample on the Font page of the Settings dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Box:

    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw_box(self):
        print('+ ' * self.width)
        for s in range(self.height-2):
            print('+ ' + ' ' * (2*(self.width-2)) + '+')
        print('+ ' * self.width)


# Create and Run code
box = Box(10,4)
box.draw_box()
```

Since you need a space after printing each '+' symbol. You should consider double the width. If you have 5 +'s to print then you will be using 10char spaces to print them. So, double the width should be included in the line `print('+ ' + ' ' * (2*(self.width-2)) + '+')`

Answer (score 0):

There are three issues with your code, all in the line `print('+ ', ' ' * (self.width-1), ' +')`:

1. If you pass two arguments to `print()`, they are printed separated by a space. Thus, you now have an offset of two spaces in this line.
2. Your second argument passed to print is a single space. However, your box is defined by `+` , which has a width of two. Therefore this space should be adjusted to a double space.
3. The last argument is  `+` instead of `+` , which also gives an offset.

Based on this, I would change `draw_box()` to:

```py
def draw_box(self):
    print('+ ' * self.width)
    spacing = '  ' * (self.width-2)
    for s in range(self.height-2):         
        print(f'+ {spacing}+ ')
    print('+ ' * self.width)
```

Comment: Even better to remove all the spaces in between so the box is actually `width` characters wide.

Comment: When I changed it to `print('+ ' + '  ' * (self.width-2) + '+')` that appeared to have solved my original problem.